# Batch copying/renaming in Google Docs

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I need to copy and rename a base form (a spreadsheet) to several other forms in Google Docs. Imagine I have the following form:

- **My Base Form - @name (@course)**

After running the script or whatever, I will end up with those forms:

- **My Form Copy - John Doe (Computer Science)**
- **My Form Copy 2 - Donald (Arts)**
- ...
- **My Form Copy 15 - Andrea (Music)**

Any idea on how can I do that?

Comment: Can you share a doc with us?

Comment: If this is about the question, never mind, I figured it out already :)

Comment: Perhaps you can share this solution with us, Q&A style?

Comment: Ok, I've shared my solution. I hope it can help. Thanks for the bootstrap, Jacob!

Answer (score 2):

After some research, I figured it myself. Here is my solution if someone faces the same problem and needs a script for that:

### Code

```
function makeForms() {
  // Google Spreadsheet ID
  var BASE_FORM_ID = "0AlDgVsiNXDhjdFlRTFVBeG5rNmprb3kHNxd1ItSFE";

  // object that holds the information 
  var aNames = [     
    {name: "Prof. Fernando", course: "Course name"},
    {name: "Prof. Rafael", course: "Course name"}
  ];

  // creation of variables
  var aSpreadsheet, aNewForm, aCurrentName = "";
  var aBaseForm = DocsList.getFileById(BASE_FORM_ID);

  // iterate over the names
  for(var i = 0; iLen = aNames.length; i < iLen; i++) {
    // set name
    aCurrentName = aNames[i].course+" ("+aNames[i].name+")";

    // make copy
    aNewForm = aBaseForm.makeCopy("Evaluation for " + aCurrentName);  

    // open spreadsheet and retrieve ID
    aSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(aNewForm.getId());

    // log the Url's 
    Logger.log(aCurrentName + "  "+aSpreadsheet.getFormUrl());
  }
}
```

### References

- [getFileById](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/docs-list/docs-list#getFileById(String))
- [makeCopy(newName)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/docs-list/file#makeCopy(String))
- [openById](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openById(String))
- [getId](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getId())
- [getFormUrl](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getFormUrl())

Comment: Sorry, I don't have the rep points to leave an actual comment (a bug with the stackoverflow system): References to how you figured this out would be helpful as I have no clue what some of these functions are doing. Moreover, commenting on the code could be just as helpful. Thanks and Regards

Comment: Not a bug. By design.

Comment: @user1059398 I started at the [Google Apps script page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles). From there, I searched for functions that would help me, such as _"how to open a spreadsheet?"_. I coded the solution by assembling my findings.